# Named pipe unknown error - Python to Qt C++

Tags: python, qt, pipe

I am trying to communicate between Qt 5.4 C++ and Python 2.7 by way of a named pipe.  I have it partially working, but there is some incompatibility I'm encountering.

On the Qt side, I have a QLocalServer object:

```
QLocalServer *localServer_;
```

After I instantiate, I starting listening on the pipe and connect the signal/slot for newConnection

```
if( localServer_->listen( settings_.localMessagePipeName() ) )
        connect( localServer_, SIGNAL( newConnection() ),
                 this,           SLOT( newServerConnection() ), Qt::DirectConnection );
    else
        qDebug() << "server listen error!";
```

My connection handler looks like this:

```
void newServerConnection()
{
    qDebug() << "pipeConnected";
    QLocalSocket *clientConnection = localServer_->nextPendingConnection();
    connect( clientConnection, SIGNAL( disconnected() ),
             clientConnection,   SLOT( deleteLater() ) );

    qDebug() << clientConnection->error();

    qDebug() << clientConnection->readAll();

    clientConnection->write( "TEST" );
    clientConnection->flush();
    clientConnection->disconnectFromServer();
}
```

In Python, I send a message down the pipe like this:

```
response = win32pipe.CallNamedPipe( pipeName, request, 512, 0 )
```

My Qt connection handler fires off.  Data is definitely coming down the pipe.  But, here's where it falls apart.  This is the output I get in Qt:

```
pipeConnected
QLocalSocket::UnknownSocketError
""
```

Note that empty string should have my random testing request value I sent from Python.

On the python end I get this result:

```
    response = win32pipe.CallNamedPipe( pipeName, request, 512, 0 )
pywintypes.error: (87, 'CallNamedPipe', 'The parameter is incorrect.')
```

I read a similar thread which said that python error is produced when the other side of the pipe is not created with PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE.  In Qt, it is though.  It doesn't seem like that is my problem.  Check this Qt source for QLocalServer : https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/network/socket/qlocalserver_win.cpp

```
listener.handle = CreateNamedPipe(
                 (const wchar_t *)fullServerName.utf16(), // pipe name
                 PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,       // read/write access
                 PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe
                 PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode
                 PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode
                 PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances
                 BUFSIZE,                  // output buffer size
                 BUFSIZE,                  // input buffer size
                 3000,                     // client time-out
                 NULL);
```

BUFSIZE is defined as 0 btw.

In Python, my test client works when I create a pipe in another Python class like this:

```
def __createPipe( self ):
        pipeName        = getPipeName( self._svc_name_ )
        openMode        = win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | win32file.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED
        pipeMode        = win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE
        nMaxInstances   = win32pipe.PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES
        nOutBufferSize  = 0 # use default size
        nInBufferSize   = 0 # use default size
        nDefaultTimeOut = (PIPE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS * 1000) # max time for pipe i/o
        securityAttribs = pywintypes.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES()      
        securityAttribs.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl( 1, None, 0 ) # full access
        self.pipeHandle_ = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe( 
            pipeName, openMode, pipeMode,
            nMaxInstances, nOutBufferSize, nInBufferSize,  
            nDefaultTimeOut, securityAttribs )
```

It seems like those pipes have the same core settings.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved my problem in another way.  I simply reversed my client/server logic!

I created a pipe server in Python and used QLocalSocket on the Qt end to send and receive messages as a pipe client.  That all worked right out of the gate for me.  The drawback was having to write a whole lot more code.

In my use case, it actually makes more sense this way, but the first way would have taken a fraction of the lines to implement (at least in Python, it's about the same in Qt).  Note that my Python side included the create pipe code I posted in my question as a sample of what worked as a server to my python client that failed with the Qt server. I didn't do anything special with QLocalSocket, it's default properties worked fine.